non-lattice packings better than best known lattice packings
In 1d the best sphere packing is just packing intervals (density $ 1 $), corresponding to the $ A_1 $ root lattice. In 2d the best sphere packing is the hexagonal lattice corresponding to $ A_2 $ root lattice (density $ \pi / \sqrt{12} \approx .9069 $). In 3d, sphere packings with the optimal density ( $ \pi /\sqrt{18} \approx .74048 $ ) include the body-centered cubic packing corresponding to the root lattice of $ A_3 $ and the face-centered cubic packing $ D_3 $ (recall that the $ A_3 $ and $ D_3 $ root lattices are equivalent e.g. $ SU(4) $ and $ SO(6) $ are isogeneous).
In 4d, the best known sphere packing is the $ D_4 $ lattice packing, with density $ \pi^2/16 \approx .61685 $.
What is the simplest or best known example of a non-lattice sphere packing that is better than any lattice packing? I'm interested in an explanation of why the non-lattice packing is denser, or a reference. Have any non-lattice packings been proved to be denser than any lattice packing?

https://mathoverflow.net/questions/60912/dense-sphere-packings-which-are-not-lattice-packings    Evidently not actually proved for dimension 10.
